# ordering resultset ö together with o

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, sql-order-by

I want to order a resultset. The columns which i want to use for ordering contain german umlauts like ö, ü and ä. I want column data with these sortet together with normal letters.
Example:

At it the Moment, the resultset is ordered like this: 
ABCOXYZÖ

I want it to be ordered like this:
ABCOÖXYZ

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

DB2 9 onwards has a COLLATION_KEY function for specifying sort order in the ORDER BY clauses:

```
ORDER BY COLLATION_KEY(field,...)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: I'm using a DB2 i5/OS V5R4... 

Tried COLLATION_KEY, but it doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

Look into changing the Sort Sequence before you run your SQL - it's the SRTSEQ parameter on the STRSQL, RUNSQLSTM or CHGJOB commands.

Comment: Or for various connections, the connection attribute would use `*LANGIDSHR` for the sort sequence. You can think of it as based on the "language identifier" some characters have a "shared weight", allowing various accented characters to sort together. Indexes usually should also be made available with that attribute.